Why publishing a asp.net core version 8 application I get the error about the web deploy provider and dbFullSql
When publishing I get the error
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.303\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\targets\PublishTargets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.MSDeploy.targets(140,5): Error : Web deployment task failed. (Make sure the database connection string for the server is correct and that you have appropriate permission to access the database. (Web Deploy Provider is "dbFullSql").
My Server Admin granted me full rights and now it allows me through. But this seems wrong and there is something missing. Any ideas which groups I need access to?
We have a shared config but I just needed access to the one server.
-
I can publish fine with standard .net 4.8.1 c# mvc applications just the new .net core that is causing issues.
